# (HTML) linked CSS stylesheet in other folder but same directory doesn't work

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am a total beginner and am trying to create a website and store the CSS stylesheet in a **different folder** that the HTML files, but in the **same directory**.

I put this in the header tag of my HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./style/stylesheet.css" />
```

but it doesn't work.

The file is in the folder "style" in the same directory as my HTML.

**It works, when I have the CSS file and the HTML file in the same folder and link to it in the same way with**
    href="stylesheet.css"

I have looked for other fixes, checked for typos, but it seems to be linked correctly already? I have also tried around different ways to type the path, but nothing works.

This is the way the folders are structured:

[image: directory layout]

Comment: Can you show us a diagram/screenshot of your directory structure?

Comment: *href="style/stylesheet.css"* should work

Comment: are you loading your html page locally `file://` or on a server ?

Comment: There's no way we can tell why this doesn't work from the information you've provided. Open the network tab in your browser's developer tools. Look at the URL that is being requested. Figure out what URL it should work. Work forward from there.

Comment: try this one. <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/stylesheet.css" /> if it didn't work, something wrong with your file local path.

Comment: @LakshmanKambam — Why? That's entirely equivalent to what they already have.

Comment: @Quentin  — read my comment properly. i didn't say anything equivalent. I simplified his css link tag and giving him a suggestion that he would've done something wrong if it didn't work.

Comment: @LakshmanKambam — The simplification is entirely equivalent.

Comment: @Quentin  —  alright there is a difference between these 2 words, please go through this link and let me know. http://www.jamit.com.au/htmlFolder/FRAC1002.html

Comment: @Quentin - Simplification means  -  Many fractions can be reduced down and written in a simpler form. The word EQUIVALENT means - the same as EQUAL or, more precisely, of equal value. (Equal as shape or value.. etc.,)

Comment: @LakshmanKambam — (a) We're talking English nor mathematics here, and (b) even using those definitions, my comments still apply.

Comment: @Quentin — I got distracted by your reply to my comment, instead giving answer to -(IvyX).  anyway no worries. Thank you for your comment. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The file is in the folder "style" in the same directory as my HTML.

No, it isn't.

The image shows that the HTML is in a folder named `LoggedIn`, and the CSS is in a folder called `style` but `style` is *not* inside `LoggedIn`. It is a sibling directory of `LoggedIn` not a subdirectory of it.

So you need to go up a level before you go down into `style`.

Replace `./` (the current directory) with `../` (the parent directory).

Answer (score 1):

According to the image structure you have there i think you should do something like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/stylesheet.css">
```

This should work just fine