# Why is my HTML link to external css not working?

Tags: html, css

Ive created a separate folder called css and created a styles.css page within it. Please let me know why my preview page is not showing my css now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
    
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="description"Yasin Zahir>
      <title>Yaso's Personal Site</title>
      <link rel = "stylesheet"
      type = "text/css"
      href = "styles.css" />
    </head>
```

Comment: Is the `styles.css` in the same folder as your HTML file.

Comment: Is there any error showing in the console?  Do you see the request for `styles.css` in the Network pane in your devtools?  If so, does it complete successfully?  What is the status, and what does the response (if any) look like?  Does the path match with what you expect?  These would be the primary means of debugging this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(HTML) linked CSS stylesheet in other folder but same directory doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52966506/html-linked-css-stylesheet-in-other-folder-but-same-directory-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 2):

You have tow options for inclusion path:

1. Relative
2. Fix

**Relative#Sample 1**

```
 -root directory
 -css
  stylesheet.css
 -index.html

    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/stylesheet.css'>
```

**Relative#Sample 2**

```
-root directory
 -css
   stylesheet.css
 -html
   index.html

    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../css/stylesheet.css'>
```

**Fixed#Sample**

```
-root directory
 -css
   stylesheet.css
 -html
   index.html

    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='[root directory]/css/stylesheet.css'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to put the full path on the link href instead of just "styles.css"

easy fix

Answer (score 0):

Please follow following step in your project `directory`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>    
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="description"Yasin Zahir>
      <title>Yaso's Personal Site</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
</html>


Follow this directory

- root directory
  - css directory
    style.css
  - index.html

or
- root directory
  style.css
  index.html

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing the type first, then replace the href value with /css/style.css